# Camel Wiretap with choice

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Spring Boot with Apache camel. I am invoking the routes from the controller. Once the route completes, the control goes back to the controller.
I am generating the response in the VerifyLimitProcessor and ApprovedLimitProcessor. If I don't provide the wiretap configuration in the route, the controller retrieves the header and the body as expected. But if I introduce wiretap in the route, the controller receives header and body as null. It will be a great help if someone points me out what I need to do so that I can introduce the wiretap configuration for both the processor, namely VerifyLimitProcessor and ApprovedLimitProcessor in the choice statement.

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

```
from(SERVICE_ENDPOINT).process(new ValidatorProcessor())
.to(bean:limitDataDaoImpl?method=getLimitData(${body}))
                .process(new AuthorizationProcessor())
                .choice()
                .when(isLimitGreater())
                .log("Limit is greater ")
                .to(bean:limitDataDaoImpl?method=getVerifiedLimit(${body}))
                .process(new VerifyLimitProcessor())
                .otherwise()
                    .process(new ApprovedLimitProcessor())

                .endChoice()
                .end()
                .wireTap("direct:auditEndPoint")
                .executorServiceRef("wireTapThreadPool");
```

Comment: I am able to handle the scenario by creating alter route.

Comment: how do you trigger the route? can you show that code

Comment: @pvpkiran `.choice()
    .when(isLimitGreater())
    .to(VERIFY_LIMIT_ROUTE)
    .otherwise()
     .to(APPROVED_LIMIT_ROUTE);`

Answer (score 0):

endChoice().end() might be the cause.
Try with the end() only. In other words, remove the endchoice()